# Android How to work with processes and a memory like WinAPI allows

Tags: java, android, process, readprocessmemory

In WinAPI I can easily interact with almost all processes via OpenProcess, VirtualQueryEx, ReadProcessMemory, WriteProcessMemory. They are well 
described in MSDN and easy to use.

Please tell me how can I interact with processes in Android...
How can I get a process memory map i.e. all regions with their attributes and base addresses... And how to correctly open another process/read another process memory... Does Android SDK have the functions or any low level programming needed...

It's not a problem getting running process list in Android but I'm stuck with opening process...

Comment: None of what you want is possible, except perhaps on rooted devices, for blindingly obvious security reasons. There is nothing in the Android SDK for this.

Comment: any updates/answers ?